# PHP variable inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to use a php variable in javascript in the following way but its not working.
Can anybody let me know what is wrong in the below code

```
include './connection.php';
$rating[]=$_GET['rating'];

echo '<script>';
echo 'document.getElementById(' .$rating. ').checked = true;';
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: If you enable error reporting you should get a message telling you what is going on. Same as when you inspect the rendered html

Comment: Remove the brackets from $rating on the second line.

Comment: try doing `echo 'document.getElementById("' .$rating. '").checked = true;';`

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to echo an array, rather than a value in the array.

Why define `$rating` as an array?  Simply do this:

```
include './connection.php';
$rating=$_GET['rating'];
?>
<script>
document.getElementById('<?php echo $rating; ?>').checked = true;
</script>
<?php
// continue script
```

You also need to think about addressing the cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities which you currently have.

Comment: If we're optimizing, why bother setting `$rating` at all? Just do `<?=$_GET['rating']?>`.

Comment: @Wogan Yes. One could do that, but really `$rating` should be sanitized before echoing it back out.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it should be a string, if so you have to quote it

```
include './connection.php';
$rating = $_GET['rating'];

echo '<script>';
echo 'document.getElementById("' .$rating. '").checked = true;';
echo '</script>'; //          ^^            ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    include './connection.php';
    $rating = $_GET['rating']; // forget the square brackets, you don't need an array made here

    echo '<script>';
    echo 'document.getElementById("' . htmlspecialchars($rating) . '").checked = true;';
    echo '</script>';
```

[htmlspecialchars](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) makes sure you're not making your site vulnerable to [Cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).
document.getElementById takes a string parameter, so you need to wrap it in quotes.

Comment: Should probably link to the english wikipedia ;)